# MongoDb with php on windows 7 64 bits

Tags: php, windows-7, 64-bit, mongodb

I installed wampserver, and mongodb both up and running i installed the mongodb extension PHP 5.3 VC6 Thread-Safe Mongo extension and added php_mongo.dll extension to php.ini, restarted the server but it won't show up in phpinfo() and of course it won;t work. Where did i skip a step ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP x86 or x64 ? Look at "Architecture" in phpinfo. Official drivers doesn't work with Apache + PHP x64.

Look at this post: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/1d2cecd9734e54fc/ff785888cb8e2c39?lnk=gst&q=x64#ff785888cb8e2c39

Comment: Yes that was it, i switched to 32 version.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**php_mongo.dll** is now available for **64 bit architecture** too. You can download the same from **github**. No need to downgrade now to 32-bit.

https://github.com/downloads/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/php_mongo-1.2.12.zip

parent link : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads

Comment: Now we can use `64-bit` version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `php_mongo.dll` is actually in the PHP exstension dir?

Comment: yes i put it there myself and in the wamp menu under php extensions i even checked it :/

Answer (score 0):

In my case Windows 7 64 bits, php-5.6.14-Win32-VC11-x64 and php_mongo-1.6.11-5.6-ts-vc11-x64
After check the VSVC Versions, configure the php.ini location, in the php.ini put the correct file the extensio_dir. And add to sytema PATH the location of php.

You need to copy libeay32.dll, libsasl.dll and ssleay32.dll into c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\syswow64

Good day.